# How to tackle this squaring of inequality problem

Tags: quadratics

> If the roots of quadratic equation     $$x^2 − 2ax + a^2 + a – 3 = 0$$ 
>   are real and less than $3$, find the range of $a$.

The roots are   $a \pm \sqrt {3 – a}$

For the roots to be real, we must have  a < 3.

Also, for the roots to be less than 3, we must have $\pm \sqrt {3 – a } \lt 3 – a $

If squaring both sides is allowable, I will get $(a – 2)(a – 3) > 0$. Then the problem is solved.

The question is:- how to convince others that the squaring of both sides of $\pm \sqrt {3 - a } \lt 3 - a $ is allowable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequality $\;\underbrace{- \sqrt {3 – a } }_{{-}}\leq \underbrace{3 – a}_{+}\;$ holds trivially.

As $\;3-a\geq 0\;$ and  $\;\sqrt {3 – a } \geq 0,\;$ squaring $\sqrt {3 – a } \geq 3 – a\;$ is legitimate, as stated by @auscrypt.

Answer (score 2):

Yes , since we have $$3\geq a$$ you can square the inequality with $+$ sign and you will get $$3-a<(3-a)^2$$ so you will get $$0<(3-a)(3-a-1)$$
$$-\sqrt{3-a}<3-a$$ is fulfilled for $$3>a$$

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to calculate the roots, nor square them – only use high-school theorems on the sign of quadratic polynomials:

1. The polynomial $p(x)=x^2 − 2ax + a^2 + a – 3$ has *real* roots, so its reduced discriminant is non-negative:
   $$\Delta'=a^2-(a^2+a-3)=3-a \ge 0,\text{ i.e. } a\le 3.$$
2. $3$ has to be *outside* the interval of the roots $x_1, x_2$: this means $p(3)=a^2-5a+6>0$. As the roots of $a^2-5a+6$ are $2$ and $3$, we must have $a<2\quad\text{or}\quad a>3$.
3. From condition 2, we know that either $3< x_1<x_2$ or $x_1<x_2<3$. In other words either  both roots are greater than $3$ or both are less. To ensure that we're in the latter case, it is enough to ensure their arithmetic mean is less than $3$. Now
   $$\frac{x_1+x_2}2=a$$
   so the condition is $a<3$.

Combining all these conditions, we obtain $\;a\in \color{red}{(-\infty,2)}$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $x_1,x_2<3$ we have $3-x_i>0$ so their product is positive:$$ 0<9-3(x_1+x_2)+x_1x_2$$
thus $$0<9-6a+a^2+a-3 = a^2-5a+6=(a-3)(a-2)$$

So $a\in (-\infty ,2)\cup (3,\infty)$. But since the discriminat must be $\geq 0$ we get $a\leq 3$ so we have $a\in (-\infty ,2)$

Now let us prove that all $a<2$ are good.

We have $$x_1= a-\sqrt{3-a}\leq a<3$$ We are left if $x_2= a+\sqrt{3-a}$ is smaller than $3$ if $a<2$ i.e. $$\sqrt{3-a} <3-a$$ which is true since $3-a>1$

Comment: True. However, it is a bit difficult to think of creating the 3rd line as the starting point of the proof.

Comment: Why is that?.....

Comment: I mean: Sum and product of roots are usually applied in a guided manner. For example, form a new quadratic equation from another known quadratic equation. But $-3(x_1+x_2)+x_1x_2 + (9)$ is a linear combination of them and the not-so-obvious part is we have to think of how they are linearly combined.

Answer (score 0):

You can square both sides of an inequality $x<y$ to get $x^2<y^2$, provided $x\geq 0$.

Comment: But we have "$- \sqrt u < u $" instead.

Comment: No, you have $\sqrt{u}<u$ since you need both $\pm\sqrt{3-a}$, i.e., $-\sqrt{u}\leq\sqrt{u}<u$

Comment: Why should I just investigate $\sqrt{u}<u$ alone  and not  $-\sqrt{u}\leq ... <u$ also?

Comment: because it follows immediately by definition of $\sqrt{}$ that $-\sqrt{u}\leq\sqrt{u}$

Comment: That is a good point. Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you will have different results while squaring both sides of

$$ \sqrt {3 - a } \lt 3 - a$$

and

$$- \sqrt {3 - a } \lt 3 - a$$

If you take square of both sides by taking this into consideration, it is allowable.

Answer (score 0):

It's not always allowable; take $a = 2.99$, then $-\sqrt{3-a} = -0.1 < 0.01 = 3-a$. But squaring both sides gives $0.01<0.0001$, which is false. The issue is that negative signs cause issues when you square, since the absolute value of the left side may be larger than the right.

To solve this problem, note that both roots are real when $a\le 3$, and note that the largest root, $a + \sqrt{3-a}$ is less than $3$. So $a + \sqrt{3-a} < 3$, and so $\sqrt{3-a} < 3-a$. Here, we are allowed to square, because there is no negative sign, which is the key. Then you solve the quadratic, which is straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid squareing inequality.

Since $2a =x_1+x_2 <6$ we have $a<3$ and $$a^2+a-3=x_1x_2 < 9$$ we have also $a^2+a-12 =(a+4)(a-3)<0$ so $a\in (-4,3)$.

Comment: Using sum and product of roots is neat but they don't seem to give the required range.

Comment: But the range of a i got is smaller then bernards. Is a=-4 realy a solution?

Comment: The combined range is a < 2. a = -4 meets the given conditions.

Comment: I don't understand. Equation if a=-4 is $x^2+8x+9=0 $ and it has no solution.

Comment: x(1) = - 6.6458 and x(2) = -1.3542

Answer (score 0):

$y=(x-a)^2+(a-3)$;

$a-3 >0:$ This parabola does not cut the $x-$axis ($(x-a)^\ge 0)$.

Hence $a-3\le 0$.

Roots:

$y=(x-a)^2 +(a-3) = 0;$

$x_{1,2}=a\pm \sqrt{3-a} <3$.

1)Let $0\le a \lt 3$ ($a=3$ is ruled out)

$\sqrt{3-a} <3-a=\sqrt{3-a}\sqrt{3-a}$.

This is true for $\sqrt{3-a} >1$, or $ 3-a >1$.

Hence $2>a \ge 0$.

2) Let $a <0$;

Then $-|a| +\sqrt{3+|a|} <3$.

$\sqrt{3+|a|} <3+|a|=\sqrt{3+|a|}\sqrt{3+|a|}.$

This is true for $\sqrt{3+|a|} >1$, or $3+|a|>1$.

Hence $a<0$;

Combining:

$a \in (-\infty, 2)$